# What are the rules when accessing a remote server with upgrades?

Tags: android-netrunner

Android netrunner has a seemingly endless and complex set of rules. I was hoping to get a clarification on how accessing a remote server works. In the rules it states you get access to all cards when accessing the server.

Say we have a server with two upgrades, one of which prevents me from getting the third card - an agenda. Even though I can't get the card I want, can I still trash the other cards in the server? Can I trash any/all of them if possible?

Thanks in advance and thanks to all the others who have already answered my netrunner questions.

Comment: When accessing multiple cards (this is the heading you are looking for in the manual), you access one at a time. So you can't look at both upgrades and the asset and then decide which to trash. You pick one at random, decide to trash or leave it, then move on to the next. You get to access all the cards in the server but only one at a time.

Comment: Oops, responded on my phone - meant to put that as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When accessing multiple cards (this is the heading you are looking for in the manual, page 18), you access one at a time. So you can't look at both upgrades and the asset and then decide which to trash. You pick one at random, decide to trash or leave it, then move on to the next. You get to access all the cards in the server but only one at a time.

Here is the relevant page from the manual:

> When accessing multiple cards, the Runner accesses them **one at a time**
>   **in any order he likes**. For example, the Runner may access a card from
>   HQ, then an upgrade installed in the root of HQ, and then another card
>   from HQ, if he has the ability to do so. When accessing multiple cards
>   from R&D, the Runner must draw them in order from the top of the deck,
>   and must return any cards not scored or trashed in reverse order, so
>   as to preserve their positions in R&D. **The Runner must fully resolve
>   his access to a card (steal it, pay to trash it, etc.) before
>   accessing the next card.** If the Runner scores an agenda that gives him
>   seven or more points, he immediately wins the game, even if he would
>   otherwise access more cards.

This means that if there is an agenda in a remote server, but also a trap and you access the trap first... it is possible to get flatlined before you win from the stolen/scored agenda.

Comment: How does it work if the corp want to rez an upgrade. For example I was playing a game when the corp had unrezzed upgrades and wanted to rez one to prevent me from getting the agenda. Is that possible?

Comment: There is an opportunity to do this.  In the FAQ (http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/Android-Netrunner%20FAQ.pdf), look at the chart on page 14 (the last page).  Between passing the last ICE and the runner accessing cards, there is a "paid abilities/unrezzed cards can be rezzed" window (4.3).  So the Corp player would have to rez the upgrade before you start accessing cards (4.5).  If you have accessed any cards, their window for paid abilities/rezzing has passed.